# What to do about our two male cats?

Tags: cats, behavior, breeding

Our oldest male cat (Bear just turned 2) and our younger male cat (Jr. will be 1 in July) keeping grabbing our youngest female (Callie was born Feb. 22, 2018) by the back of the neck & climbing on her.

We do have two older females. Mittens (Bear's sister and she just got fixed a few weeks ago) and Princess (Jr's sister). Bear doesn't try to mate with the two older females and never tried before. Jr. does try to mate with both even with Mittens after she got fixed.

We do have Callie's sister which are from Mittens last litter. We also have Princess's four kittens from her first litter which where born March 29, 2018. We are confused on why both male cats are going after Callie. We are only keeping the 5 cats we named. We are planning to get the other 4 fix asap.

Can someone please help us figure out what is going on please. We have tried keeping the males away from the females, spraying water on them, and yell at them. We don't know what else to do.

Also with our two older females we are having an issue. Princess keeps going after Mittens aggressively and acts like a bully at times. Other times she cleans her, rubs against her, and will even lay with her. Princess is from Mittens first litter. We love all our cats very much but they are starting to stress us out. They always have fresh water (5 bowls) and food (6 bowls). When we give them can food or treats, we places it down so they all can eat at the same time. They all get along with no issues while eating.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour for tomcats. They will try to mount spayed females, intact females, other males, sometimes inanimate objects. As much as wanting to breed with them it is a display of dominance. It is also worth noting that cats will mate with their siblings, their parents, their own kittens.

No amount of yelling or water spraying is going to dampen their instict to mount or mate.

Your answer is really in the question – you need to get everyone spayed and neutered as soon as possible. I would start with the males if costs or time is a concern – neutering is a quick and inexpensive procedure.

In the meantime you must keep the unneutered males and females separate. I would keep them separate at all times, including meal times.

A female cat can become pregnant as early as 4 months old. If you are not careful, you will end up with more kittens than you can find good homes for. There is nothing wrong with responsible breeding, but be aware that there are thousands of kittens out there that deserve a good home and will never find one.